# Hiding uiimage when Pushed to other view controller

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

I am adding Uiimageview as a subview to tabbarcontroller.view. when i pushed to other view controller tabbarcontroller gets hided but the image is appearing while pushing to other class.Inside the tabbarcontroller all the tabbar item is a navigation controller. I didnt add tabbar inside the tabbarcontroller
 Here is my code:

```
imgV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428, 320, 48)];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  
tabBarController.delegate=self;
```

//  tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;

```
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"home_selected.png"];
[imgV setImage:img];
//    [imgV setAlpha:0.5];

[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:imgV];
[self.tabBarController.view  bringSubviewToFront:imgV];
[imgV release];



Dashboard_iPhone *dash = [[Dashboard_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem0 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dash] autorelease];
tabItem0.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    TrackProgram_iPhone *rep = [[TrackProgram_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rep] autorelease];
tabBarController.tabBarItem.title=@"TrackProgram";  
tabItem1.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


TrackClinic_iPhone *loc = [[TrackClinic_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loc] autorelease];
tabBarController.tabBarItem.title=@"TrackClinic ";
tabItem2.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];



tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem0,tabItem1,tabItem2,nil];


[self.view insertSubview:tabBarController.view belowSubview:dash.view ];    

[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

when i Pushed to other class

```
    -(void)logoutBtnTap
{
appDelegate.enterLogout=YES;
for(UIImageView *view in[self.view subviews])

{
    for(UIImage *img in view.subviews){//remove photoes from the subview
        [img removeFromSuperview]; 
    }
    [view removeFromSuperview];

}


Login_iPhone *controller=[[Login_iPhone alloc]init];
[controller setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[acctExec_iPhone.imgV removeFromSuperview];
acctExec_iPhone.imgV.hidden=YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

}

Comment: Double post of [Hiding Imageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989224/hiding-imageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment your older question.

[Hiding Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989224/hiding-imageview/9989356#9989356)

beacuse hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=yes is mean your tabBarController hide tabbar not view.

Be a point of caution, you will need to add to imageView in tabBar not view.

maybe this method send to message tabBarController.tabBar subviews, when a operate push or pop object controller.

so, your imgV add to tabbar. here for example.

```
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"home_selected.png"];
[imgV setImage:img];

[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imgV];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar bringSubviewToFront:imgV];
```

but carefully tabBarController.tabBar height-size different tabBarController.view

so, you frame should set size or coordinates.

Comment: I tried by Adding the imageview to my tabbarcontroller.tabar. if i do like that then the image itself not appearing.

Comment: are you remove [for(UIImageView *view in[self.view subviews])

{
    for(UIImage *img in view.subviews){//remove photoes from the subview
        [img removeFromSuperview]; 
    }
    [view removeFromSuperview];

}] this code. retry your project?